# Checking a form controls email validator in another custom validator in Angular

Tags: typescript, validation, angular7

New to Angular and trying to figure out how to check my email field to see if it's a valid email address so that I can check it against my server for emails already in use.

I have this field in the form with these validators

```
this.registerForm = this.fb.group({    
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, this.emailMatchValidator]],
}
```

My custom validator looks like this but can't seem to figure out how to correctly check if the email address is valid. And only if it's valid do I check it against the server for other emails in use.

```
emailMatchValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
// I want to check if we have a valid email address
// let alwaysTrue = control.valid;
// let alwaysValid = control.value.valid;
// let alwaysUndefined = control.value.hasError;
// let regFormUndefined = this.registerForm.get('email').hasError('email');
// let showsValid = control.status; // when value is "c"
}
```

Comment: Have a look at my library Easy Angular, makes form validation a breeze. https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez and a demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pytks5

Comment: Not looking for a lib to use for validation...

Comment: The library is for building form, takes all the work out of it and validation just works.

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to Angular and not yet looking for a lib. Just want to know where my syntax is incorrect and how to correct it.

Comment: Your validator needs to be an asyncValidator, since it needs to make an asynchronous request to your server. Abd [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#async-validation) says *the asynchronous validation happens after the synchronous validation, and is performed only if the synchronous validation is successful*. So, once you make it an async validator, the problem goes aways.

Comment: just curious, why is it an asyncvalidator if it must return a value before I can validate the form? Shouldn't it be a synchronous validator?

Comment: How do you intend to make an HTTP request to your server in a synchronous way? If you obtain the result of the validation in an asynchronous way (and thus return an Observable<validation result> rather than a validation result, then it's called an asynchronous validator.

Comment: Not sure I understand that question. Maybe I don't know Angular that well, yet, but can't the calls be done sync or async ?

Comment: No. A http request is always asynchronous.